# Python method argument management

Tags: python, methods, arguments, eval, default

I have a method in a class which can be called with different combinations of arguments.  The defaults depend on the value of a class attribute.  Here is how I currently manage the argument checking:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.a = something
    ...
    ...
    def my_method(self, a,b,c **kwargs):
        # a, b, and c are always required
        # if self.a = something, we have optional keyword arguments d and e
        # if self.a = something else, we have optional keyword arguments e and f
        # default for e depends on value of self.a


        # argument checking
        if self.a == something:
            if 'd' in kwargs.keys():
                d = kwargs['d']
            else:
                d = default value
            if 'e' in kwargs.keys():
                e = kwargs['e']
            else:
                e = default value
        else:
            if 'e' in kwargs.keys():
                e = kwargs['e']
            else:
                e = default value (different from above)
            if 'f' in kwargs.keys():
                f = kwargs['f']
            else:
                f = default value
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I was thinking of something like a default dictionary.

```
    ...
    defaults = {something:{'d': default value,
                           'e': default value,},
                something else:{'e': default value,
                                'f': default value,}}[self.a]
    for arg_str in defaults.keys():
       if arg_str in kwargs.keys():
           eval('%s=%s' % (arg_str, kwargs[arg_str]))
       else:
           eval('%s=%s' % (arg_str, defaults[arg_str]))
```

I think this would work, but I hate using the eval() function.  Is there a better way?  Help me style gurus!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to Do Too Much In The Constructor.  Have you considered using a factory design pattern?

Comment: you can do something like `self.__dict__[name] = val` to avoid eval

Comment: __init__ method should have def before it.. and both methods need the self argument as first argument.. just saying

Comment: you say you think this would work.. have you tried this and does it actually work?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your lines where you check for d and in in kwargs, with the dict class's get function. Call d = kwargs.get('d',defaultvalue). If d is in kwargs, then it's all good. If not, it returns defaultvalue or none if unspecified.

```
    if self.a == something:
        d = kwargs.get('d',defd)
        e = kwargs.get('e',defe1)
    else:
        e = kwargs.get('e',defe2)
        f = kwargs.get('f',deff)
```